# How to apply shadow on the right side only and hidde the bottom border?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have created a nav-bar with bootstrap where I want to do the trick that the active tab is above the others, and I got something like this:

[image: ![,ht]

That was fine i guess, now I had to do some trick to join the tab with the content and with a before class It worked fine:

[image]

Now I'm applying this class to the .active that bootstrap creates so the effect works, my problem is when I swap between tabs I can see the hugly trick one second:

[image]

**Is there a way to solve this issue or hide the bottom shadow other way?** I have tryed with on hidden.bs.tab, shown.bs.tab with no success alredy.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<style>
  ul.custom-nav-tab {
     border-bottom: 0px !important;
     margin-left: 20px;
     font-weight: 800;
  }
   ul.custom-nav-tab li a.active {
     background-color: #ffeed2 !important;
     border-color: #fff0 !important;
  }
   ul.custom-nav-tab li a {
     box-shadow: 1px 2px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
     padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
     color: inherit;
     border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px !important;
     background-color: #fef7ea !important;
  }
   div.custom-nav-tab {
     position: relative;
     border-radius: 10px;
     background-color: #ffeed2;
     padding: 20px;
     box-shadow: 1px 2px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
   .custom-nav-active-tab {
     position: relative;
  }
   .custom-nav-active-tab:before {
     content: "";
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     height: 15px;
     background-color: #ffeed2;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: -5px;
     left: 0;
     z-index: 10;
  }
</style>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs custom-nav-tab" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Hotel + Actividad</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Hotel</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content custom-nav-tab" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active tab1" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab"> <p>Donec mattis laoreet suscipit. Donec blandit quam sed justo mattis, et hendrerit leo sodales. Donec elit leo, sollicitudin sed purus vitae, iaculis iaculis lacus. Proin quis leo a purus gravida ultricies. Nam molestie a nisi sed scelerisque. Proin in suscipit sem, in viverra libero. Proin quam diam, consequat vitae arcu eget, egestas ultrices eros. Donec sed fermentum lorem. Nam dolor sem, aliquam dapibus rutrum id, tempor ac leo. Vestibulum in neque id eros tristique lacinia. Duis a bibendum dolor, nec cursus eros. Morbi quis enim eu quam gravida lacinia. Etiam tincidunt venenatis felis quis pellentesque. Sed sagittis elit vitae arcu malesuada, quis dapibus libero porttitor.
          </p></div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade tab2" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab"> <p>xxxxxDonec mattis laoreet suscipit. Donec blandit quam sed justo mattis, et hendrerit leo sodales. Donec elit leo, sollicitudin sed purus vitae, iaculis iaculis lacus. Proin quis leo a purus gravida ultricies. Nam molestie a nisi sed scelerisque. Proin in suscipit sem, in viverra libero. Proin quam diam, consequat vitae arcu eget, egestas ultrices eros. Donec sed fermentum lorem. Nam dolor sem, aliquam dapibus rutrum id, tempor ac leo. Vestibulum in neque id eros tristique lacinia. Duis a bibendum dolor, nec cursus eros. Morbi quis enim eu quam gravida lacinia. Etiam tincidunt venenatis felis quis pellentesque. Sed sagittis elit vitae arcu malesuada, quis dapibus libero porttitor.
          </p></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav-item:has(a.active)").addClass("custom-nav-active-tab");
  });

  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('hidden.bs.tab', function (e) {
      $(".nav-item, a").not(".active").removeClass("custom-nav-active-tab");
      $(".nav-item:has(a.active)").addClass("custom-nav-active-tab");
  });
</script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you try it with focus? for example .yourDiv:focus { z-index: 100}

Comment: @Ifaruki tryed but not working, if you can explain a bit more your idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the pseudo element trick on the `a` and consider `inherit` as value of background color. This will reduce or make the bad effect unnoticeable

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<style>
  ul.custom-nav-tab {
     border-bottom: 0px !important;
     margin-left: 20px;
     font-weight: 800;
  }
   ul.custom-nav-tab li a.active {
     background-color: #ffeed2 !important;
     border-color: #fff0 !important;
  }
   ul.custom-nav-tab li a {
     box-shadow: 1px 2px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
     padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
     color: inherit;
     border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px !important;
     background-color: #fef7ea !important;
  }
   div.custom-nav-tab {
     position: relative;
     border-radius: 10px;
     background-color: #ffeed2;
     padding: 20px;
     box-shadow: 1px 2px 7px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
   .custom-nav-active-tab {
     position: relative;
  }
   .custom-nav-active-tab a:before {
     content: "";
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     height: 15px;
     background-color: inherit;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     z-index: 10;
  }
</style>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs custom-nav-tab" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Hotel + Actividad</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Hotel</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content custom-nav-tab" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active tab1" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab"> <p>Donec mattis laoreet suscipit. Donec blandit quam sed justo mattis, et hendrerit leo sodales. Donec elit leo, sollicitudin sed purus vitae, iaculis iaculis lacus. Proin quis leo a purus gravida ultricies. Nam molestie a nisi sed scelerisque. Proin in suscipit sem, in viverra libero. Proin quam diam, consequat vitae arcu eget, egestas ultrices eros. Donec sed fermentum lorem. Nam dolor sem, aliquam dapibus rutrum id, tempor ac leo. Vestibulum in neque id eros tristique lacinia. Duis a bibendum dolor, nec cursus eros. Morbi quis enim eu quam gravida lacinia. Etiam tincidunt venenatis felis quis pellentesque. Sed sagittis elit vitae arcu malesuada, quis dapibus libero porttitor.
          </p></div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade tab2" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab"> <p>xxxxxDonec mattis laoreet suscipit. Donec blandit quam sed justo mattis, et hendrerit leo sodales. Donec elit leo, sollicitudin sed purus vitae, iaculis iaculis lacus. Proin quis leo a purus gravida ultricies. Nam molestie a nisi sed scelerisque. Proin in suscipit sem, in viverra libero. Proin quam diam, consequat vitae arcu eget, egestas ultrices eros. Donec sed fermentum lorem. Nam dolor sem, aliquam dapibus rutrum id, tempor ac leo. Vestibulum in neque id eros tristique lacinia. Duis a bibendum dolor, nec cursus eros. Morbi quis enim eu quam gravida lacinia. Etiam tincidunt venenatis felis quis pellentesque. Sed sagittis elit vitae arcu malesuada, quis dapibus libero porttitor.
          </p></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav-item:has(a.active)").addClass("custom-nav-active-tab");
  });

  $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('hidden.bs.tab', function (e) {
      $(".nav-item, a").not(".active").removeClass("custom-nav-active-tab");
      $(".nav-item:has(a.active)").addClass("custom-nav-active-tab");
  });
</script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now I can't apreciate the bad effect, only the transaction betwen tabs where you can see the z-index, but I'll get your solution it solved my problem, thanks and I learned something new about inherit :P